# Unable access elements inside Xelement directly

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

I have this XML inside an Xelement object called `request`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0">
    <List>
        <nc:Title/>
        <nc:Text/>
        <nc:Value/>
        <nc:ID>1234567890</nc:ID>
    </List>
</Message>
```

I can reach the value of the ID element by using:

```
request.Elements().Where(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName = "List").Value
```

However, this concatenates all the values of the elements inside the `<List>` element. According to what I have read, I should be able to get the value of an element by:

```
request.Element("ID")
```

...But I think the namespaces interfere. 
I am unable to directly query any of the four elements nested inside the List element. I have read several posts and tried several variations, but have had no luck. Please help :)

Example of reading xml into xelement and querying for ID which returns a value of Nothing:

```
 Dim tester As XElement = XElement.Load("C:\test.xml")
 Dim value As String = tester.Elements.Where(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName = "ID").Value
```

Comment: Did you use proper `XNamespace` instance in your queries?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek where would I use a namespace in my query?

Comment: Show what's hidden under `...all my namespaces` and an example of query that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `XNamespace` instance:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt")
Dim nc = XNamespace.Get("http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0")

Dim value = doc.Root.Element("List").Element(nc + "ID")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I had tried something similar, but must have been using the wrong namespace class. I also found that the Descendants method gives me a deeper level granularity into my Xelement, so I can also get the values of elements by: `Dim value As String = tester.Descendants.Where(Function(e) e.Name.LocalName = "ID")`

Comment: @Sanpopo `Descendants` performs traverse deep down the document tree, so it almost always checks a lot of unnecessary items. That's why you should use `Element`/`Elements` instead - it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use XmlNamespaceManager. Let's suppose that your xml is in `myfile.xml`. Name spaces are missing in your code so I used Microsoft ones instead.

```
Dim reader As New XmlTextReader("myfile.xml")
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(reader)
Dim nsmanager As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmanager.AddNamespace("nc", "www.microsoft.com/books")
nsmanager.AddNamespace("default", "www.microsoft.com/store")
Dim book as XmlNode 
Dim root as XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
book = root.SelectSingleNode("//nc:ID", nsmanager)
```

Code is built from MS samples and was never run. Please apologize mistakes.
For more information see:
[Manage Namespaces Using the XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6730bwt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[XmlNode.SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/h0hw012b.aspx)

Comment: Do I need to do this if I am using an Xelement object?

Comment: If you need XPath (I am not sure) and you have namespaces you cannot get out wihout XmlNamespaceManager. Otherwise please specify more clearly what do you mean by "access elements".

Comment: Access/obtain the value inside the element.